# How to edit visual appearance of mod in Euro Truck Simulator 2(ETS2)

Tags: modding, simulations, pc

Not sure if this is the right place, so here goes nothing...

I want to update my truck's appearance in-game, to make it more on par with it's real life counterpart. The part of the truck I want to edit, to be more specific, is the grill of the truck. The truck's looks are pretty outdated, and it seems it needs a facelift.

From what I found, all my sources tell me that I need to edit the base files of the game, and then I can alter the game mod itself. Is there a simpler way of updating the truck's appearance? Or am I better of just sticking with it's old looks?

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me what you're asking here. Maybe include a link to one of the sources you're referencing, and describe what step in the process you're unsure about? Most of us here aren't dedicated Euro Truck Simulator 2 modders, so it's likely the sources you've found are more reliable than our off-the-cuff guesses. ;)

Comment: Ok. I will. Just got to find it again. Long story short, I want to edit the grill of the modded truck, to make it look more like it's modern real counterpart, without doing this "editing the base files" nonsense. Thanks for the reply though

Comment: It would help if you can clarify what "base files" are in your terminology, as that's not a standard term we use. If you mean the truck's mesh or texture files, you may be out of luck, as that's exactly where such edits would need to be made, typically.

Comment: Ah. I see. The base files were called .sii files. I would have a better chance of asking the mod makers for an update then doing it myself